# How can I run the rustdoc lints on every crate in my workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

Rustdoc offers some pretty useful lints for documentation. I'd like to check these lints as part of continuous integration for all of the crates in my Cargo workspace.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a way to run these lints for all of my crates. You can do e.g.

`cargo rustdoc -p crate -- -D rustdoc::broken-intra-doc-links`

to run on a specific crate, but there's no `--workspace` flag on `cargo rustdoc`. Obviously I could do some hacky thing with `xargs` here, but that's pretty slow & annoying. Is there a supported way to run this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RUSTDOCFLAGS` and `cargo doc`:

```
RUSTDOCFLAGS="-D rustdoc::broken-intra-doc-links" cargo doc
```